# Compare associative array with simple array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a simple session array and I'm pushing page titles in it, as strings:

```
$_SESSION['sesArray'][] = $pageTitle;
```

and another predefined associative array with page titles and links:

```
$assoc=array(array('title' => 'page title', 'link' => 'page link'));
```

The session array gets flooded with titles so I'm taking out duplicates:

```
$array1 = array_unique($_SESSION['sesArray']);
```

My question is: how can I compare the $assoc array against $array1 to check for page titles that exist in both and eliminate them, ending up with another array that contains unique titles along with the link?
I have tried using:

```
$result= array_diff_key($assoc, $array1 );
```

But some duplicate titles are indeed removed and some are not.

Any ideas?

ETA data:

```
$array1= array('Museum', 'Club'); 
$assoc= array(array('title' => 'Museum', 'link' => 'museum.php' ),
              array('title' => 'club', 'link' => 'club.php'));
```

Comment: please provide example content for `$assoc`, `$array1` and `$result` so we can see what is removed and what is not.

Comment: @dnagirl using array_diff_key I get a $result with entries that are found in both arrays and some that aren't:
    $array1= ( [1] => Museum [2] => Club )
    $assoc=  Array ( [title] => Museum [link] => museum.php )
Array ( [title] => club [link] => club.php)

Comment: So an ideal $result would only be Array ( [title] => Martin [link] => martin.php) but I am getting all 3 and I don't know why. Is there another way I could approach this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not really doing a diff because an array of arrays is by definition going to have nothing in common with an array of scalars.  What you need to do is *filter* `$assoc` based on the contents of `$array1`. Try this:

```
$array1= array('Museum','Club');
$assoc= array(array('title' => 'Museum', 'link' => 'museum.php' ),
        array('title' => 'club', 'link' => 'club.php'));

$fn = function($arr) use ($array1) {
    return !in_array($arr['title'], $array1);
};
$result =array_filter($assoc, $fn);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I thought that might be the problem so I eventually used both as regular arrays and after I have made the comparison and eliminated duplicates I have filtered it in a for loop and added the links by association.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the infamous tech-interview problem ("compare 2 arrays and to find common entries").

try something along the lines of:

```
$ass = array_keys($assoc);

foreach($ass as $a)
{
   while (isset($_SESSION['sesArray'][$a]))
   {
     unset($_SESSION['sesArray'][$a]);
   }
}
```

The way PHP associates its tuple arrays allows you to avoid the ugly O(n^2) complexity of this issue.